# How can I select 1 to 100 number range in text box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have one text box  and I want to give range like `1 to 100` number how I can give.
And I'm using `codeigniter`

Comment: Are u looking for validation? Of a number?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple `number` input with `min` value 1 and `max` value 100?

```html
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"><br>
```